# Changing a border according to the database

Tags: javascript, php, sql, pdo

I have a database with 2 tables:

**members** table and **shows** table

I have 2 pages: `search.php` and `results.php`

I manage to display all the fields I want from the table `shows` (ie: if I type "Parks & Recreation" in my 'search.php' page, I get all the information (name, actors,...) displayed in the page named 'results.php'.

I've tried different solutions including:

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_bordercolor.asp

I know I am supposed to use:
`document.getElementById("myDiv").style.borderColor = 'red'`

The thing I don't know how to do is how to get the last bit of this code to react to my sql code.

```
<div class="container">
    <?php
    include_once("inc/search.inc.php");
    if ($resultat->rowCount() > 0) { ?>
        <ul>
            <?php while ($search = $resultat->fetch()) { ?>
            <li><?= $search['titre'] ?></li>
            <li><?= $search['category'] ?></li>
            <li><?= $search['type'] ?></li>
            <?php 
        } ?>
        </ul>
        <?php 
    } else { ?>
        Sorry, no results for <?= $term ?>...
        <?php 
    } ?>
</div>
<script>
function myFunction() {document.getElementById("container").style.border = <?php $resultat = $cooking->query('SELECT color FROM shows');?>;
}
</script>
```

I would like the border to react to the field 'color' in the table show .
In this example of 'Parks & Recreation', I would like to get the border to be green.

Comment: Without looking a lot at your code, I have a couple of quick questions: `resultat ` would hold a row, you would still need to access the `color` field, right? Your `myFunction` method is not being called from anywhere. You should still call it somewhere, right? ETA: Also, is your query only returning one row? Should you access the first row only?

Comment: Seems like you should be able to do this with inline styling, no JavaScript at all required.

Answer (score 0):

You are very close

On this line

```
document.getElementById("container").style.borderColor = <?php $resultat = $cooking->query('SELECT color FROM shows);?>;
```

I don't know what **$cooking->query** returns, but the way you can figure it out is this:

Add a line in your code like so:

```
<?php var_dump($cooking->query('SELECT color FROM shows')); ?>
```

This will let you see what is coming back from **$cooking->query**

It is likely an array will be returned

If it is an array, you can get the color from the element like so

```
$shows[0]['color']
```

**$shows** is an array, **[0]** means you want to use the first element in the array (the array indices are zero-based), and **'color'** means you would like the contents of the color column

Once you have the color from the database, you can embed it in the JavaScript.  Be sure to put quotes around it.

I would code it like this:

```
 <?php $resultat = $cooking->query('SELECT color FROM shows WHERE show_id = 1');?>
 document.getElementById("container").style.borderColor = "<?= $resultat[0]['color'] ?>";
```

You need a **WHERE** to indicate which show you want the color for.  You might use an id like **show_id**, or the name of the show.

```
document.getElementById("container").style.borderColor = "<?= $resultat[0]['color'] ?>";
```